# android fragment working on api 3.0 but not on 2.2

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-fragments

i m using eclipse. i did add the support library. the same code works on any device or emulator with with an epi hiegher then 3.0, but not 2.2
this is the code

```
  public class Main_View extends FragmentActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);   
    }
}
```

The xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="com.oent.bib_med.Cathegorie_List"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.oent.bib_med.Books_List"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
         />



</LinearLayout>
```

the fragments classes have the same code

```
public class Books_List extends ListFragment{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        String[] books = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"};

        ArrayAdapter <String> booksAdapter = 
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,books );
        setListAdapter(booksAdapter);

    }

}
```

LoCcat:
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:347)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.internal.widget.WeightedLinearLayout
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:340)
10-06 00:41:33.044: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  ... 38 more

Comment: Without a stack trace, we can't be of too much help. Double check that your `ListFragment`s are subclasses of `android.support.v4.app.ListFragment`

Comment: yes it is a subclass of android.support.v4.app.ListFragment

Comment: What does the LogCat print?

Comment: You're creating an Array Adapter for a Fragment, then setting it as a ListAdapter. Create a ListAdapter instead.

Answer (score 1):

The layout `simple_list_item_activated_1` does not exist in API's lower than 11. This is why it crashes.